# android how to compare between simpleCursorAdapter and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have an application. I want to optimize that one. how can i do that. 
For example I am using simpleCursorAdapter to bind listview and it fetch data from database.
But if i retrieve data from cursor into an string array and then by using ArrayAdapter I can bind listview.
So I want to know which one is the better one means which takes less time to binding or takes less CPU time.
Plz give me the answer.
And if u have any extra tips of code optimization then tell me plz.
Thank you

Comment: Why are you asking other people to measure performance metrics for you, when you should be able to do it easily yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to test by your self. Have a look on the following steps to check performance difference

Create a sample application where you write both of the technique. also print two print statements for displaying and free heap memory

**one statement** before calling database
**second statement** after creation of list view

In this way you can find which technique is better as per your requirement.

Thanks
Deepak